# Vuetify DataTable hide grouping for expand

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, datatable, vuetify.js

I'm using v-data-table with show-group-by, single-expand and show-expand props.
I used groupable property for the headers to hiding the groupable icon for specific columns and I want to disable the groupable icon too for the column that appears when using expand but I can't find nothing in the docs about it.

Anybody knows how?
Thanks.

Comment: It would be better if you include your current code with some data

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I added `data-table-expand` in the headers array with groupable in false:

```
{ value: 'data-table-expand', groupable: false }
```